# How to attach default equilizer( Sound effect ) of android with mediaplayer in our android app

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am working on a Music player. I want to add default Equalizer ( Sound effect) in my music player app. I successfully add it to my player app but sound effect not working on the media player of my android app. No effect when I change Jazz, Pop, Rock, Folk etc.. how to attach it which current media player in our Android app.
I open it with Intent

```
 val intent = Intent(AudioEffect.ACTION_DISPLAY_AUDIO_EFFECT_CONTROL_PANEL)

            if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null)
            {
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1234)
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

This link has quiet a lot of information on how to create an equalizer from scratch
https://www.101apps.co.za/articles/perfect-sound-using-the-equalizer-effect-a-tutorial.html

If this is not what you are looking for, perhaps a bit more info could be helpful.

To clear the basics: make sure you are creating the equalizer and attaching it to the media player. Also make sure you are setting up the UI by calling the setupEqualizerFxAndUI.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I already go through it. I do not want to create a new one. I only want to attach system equalizer with the media player of our app. How can I do this..???

Comment: assuming your media player instance is initialized and started using mediaplayer.start();

you must initalize your equalizer instance as follows:

equalizer = new Equalizer(0,mediaplayer.getAudioSessionId());

0 is the priority of the equalizer and the second parameter is to pass the sessionId of the media player to your equalizer so they can be in sync.

follow this by setting your equalized to be enabled with:

equalizer.setEnabled(true);

Comment: I add this but still not working                                                
                                                                                                           
            mp.reset();
            mp.setDataSource(songPath);
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
           equalizer = new 
                                     Equalizer(0,mp.getAudioSessionId());
           equalizer.setEnabled(true)

Comment: Did you setup the UI interface with a method call to setupEqualizerFxAndUI()?

Comment: No, I did not. is it necessary for system equalizer to use in our Android app

Comment: You need to setup the UI interface.